# Determining version of easy_install/setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools, easy-install

I'm trying to install couchapp, which uses easy_install - and is quite explicit in stating a particular version of easy_install/setuptools is needed: 0.6c6. I seem to have easy_install already on my Mac, but there's no command-line arguments to check the version. Instead of just installing a new version over the top, I'd like to see whether it's necessary first.

So: Any pointers on how I can see what version of setuptools/easy_install I have installed on my machine?

I'm not a Python developer, so I'm assuming this is a simple question. However, I've not found anything via Google or here on SOF.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One way would be to look at the actual source file for easy_install. Do

```
which easy_install
```

to see where it's located, and then use that path in

```
less path/to/easy_install
```

The second line in my easy_install script says:

```
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'setuptools==0.6c11','console_scripts','easy_install'
```

which suggests that I have easy_install version 0.6c11.

Comment: My file had no version information at all - which I'm assuming means it's too old. Thanks for the pointers, have installed a new version, everything seems fine thus far.

Comment: My version of easy_setup does not have that information anywhere in it, nor does it have a --version flag(!!).  I ended up having to look in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ to see what egg was installed  (OS X).

Answer (score 81):

This seems to get a lot of hits from google, so I thought I'd update for those folks.  I was able to do:

```
easy_install --version
```

which produced the output

```
setuptools 3.4.3
```

I believe this only works for some (newer?) versions of setuptools

Comment: Mine prints `setuptools 2.0`. This will work for Windows users too.

Comment: Mine prints setuptools 1.1.6.  Seems likely this may be all=)

Comment: I get `ImportError: No module named extern` when I think I'm running setuptools 28.8.0.  Probably related to https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/738

Answer (score 13):

On Windows, where Python is in the Path:

```
python -m easy_install --version
```

For me, I get
setuptools 7.0
as the response.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have easy_install, this worked for me:

```
$ python
Python 3.10.0
>>> import setuptools
>>> setuptools.__version__
```

Solution found [here](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/setuptools).