# easy_install gets wrong pip version

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv, pip, setuptools

I have been following the instructions on http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/osx/ but for some reason this is not going as I believe it would be expected.

I have python 2.7 running by default but had to get easy_install up-to-date by following the instructions on: https://superuser.com/questions/256717/easy-install-the-wrong-version-of-python-modules-mac-os and link it from /usr/local/bin/share to /usr/local/bin. It seems to be working fine.

The problem is that now when I install pip it seems to install to 2.6 and not 2.7.

```
    darky:~ user$ easy_install --upgrade pip
    Searching for pip
    Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
    Reading http://pip.openplans.org
    Reading http://www.pip-installer.org
    Best match: pip 1.1
    Processing pip-1.1-py2.6.egg
    pip 1.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
    Installing pip script to /usr/local/bin
    Installing pip-2.6 script to /usr/local/bin

    Using /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.6.egg
    Processing dependencies for pip
    Finished processing dependencies for pip
```

After the comments from MartijnPieters this problem **NO LONGER** persists

```
    darky:~ user$ /usr/local/share/python/easy_install-2.7 pip
    Searching for pip
    Best match: pip 1.1
    Processing pip-1.1-py2.7.egg
    pip 1.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
    Installing pip script to /usr/local/share/python
    Installing pip-2.7 script to /usr/local/share/python
    Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg
    Processing dependencies for pip
    Finished processing dependencies for pip
    darky:~ user$ pip install virtualenv --upgrade
    Requirement already up-to-date: virtualenv in /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages
    Cleaning up...
```

But pip still creates environments with python-2.6. So I have to point it to the proper pyhton interpreter.

```
    darky:pytravisci pedrorodrigues$ virtualenv --python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7 ENV
    Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/bin/python2.7
    New python executable in ENV/bin/python
    Installing setuptools............................done.
    Installing pip...............done.
```

Comment: Your easy_install is using python 2.6 because that is what it was installed for. Is there a easy_install-2.7 present?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determining version of easy_install/setuptools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956646/determining-version-of-easy-install-setuptools)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611730/how-to-run-easy-install-using-a-particular-python-version

Comment: Same problem there: `pip` is the 2.6 version. Find the 2.7 version (perhaps called pip-2.7).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I gave it another try, see the updated question

Comment: note the part "Installing pip-2.7 script to /usr/local/share/python".

Comment: I guess that's me getting tired, I couldn't see it right in front of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
easy_install-2.7
```

or if you don't have that alias:

```
python2.7 -m easy_install <stuff>
```

For pip:

```
pip2.7
```